# How to Compress Dynamic Programming States for a Modified Stair Climbing Problem?

Tags: dynamic-programming

In this specific problem, I'm trying to compress the states for dynamic programming. It builds upon the classic stair-climbing problem but adds constraints on the number of times you can jump each step size. Without these constraints, I can solve it using a one-dimensional dynamic programming array. However, with the added constraints, there are many more states to consider, and I'm unsure how to handle them. I hope someone can provide some insights or approaches to this problem. The detailed problem description is as follows. Thank you in advance!

**Description**
There is a stair-climbing game with a total of N steps.
The starting point is on the 1st step, and the goal is to reach the Nth step by jumping multiple times.
In each jump, you can choose to jump 1, 2, 3, ...M steps at your discretion, but there's a limit on the total number of times you can make each type of jump. This is represented by an array, where each number indicates the maximum number of times you can jump that many steps. For example, (4, 3, 2) means you can jump 1 step up to 4 times, 2 steps up to 3 times, and 3 steps up to 2 times.
How many different ways are there to reach the Nth step?

**Note:
**
Don't consider moving backward.
Different jump sequences count as different results.

**Input format:
**The first line has two numbers, N and M. This means there are N steps in total and you can jump anywhere from 1 to M steps in a single jump. Where N<5000, M<50000.
The second line contains M numbers, representing the maximum number of times you can jump each number of steps.

**Output format:
**Output a positive integer. As the result might be large, please output the result modulo 1000007.

```
/**
 * State: Total number of steps, N
 * dp[i]: The number of ways to jump for a stairway with a total of i steps is dp[i]
 * Choices: From the current step, one can choose to jump from 1 to N-M steps
 * Base case: dp[1]=1; when there's only one step, there's only one way to jump
 * State Transition: dp[i] = dp[i-1] + dp[i-2] + ... + dp[i-m]. For instance, when N=7 and M=2, dp[7] = dp[6] + dp[5]. If you're on step 4, you can at most jump to step 6 and cannot reach step 7.
 * @param n Total number of steps
 * @param m Maximum number of steps one can jump at a time
 * @return
 */

 public static int jumpWithoutLimits(int n, int m){
        int[] dp = new int[n+1];
        for(int i = 2; i<= n; i++){
            dp[i] = 0;
        }
        dp[0]=0;dp[1]=1;
        for(int i = 2;i<=n;i++){
            // dp[i] = dp[i-1]+dp[i-2]...+dp[i-m];
            for(int j =1;j<=m & i-j > 0;j++){
                dp[i] = dp[i]+ dp[i-j];
            }
        }
        return dp[n];
    }
```

Comment: What may be the point in jumping up to 49999 steps if there are only up to 4999 steps in total?